# CSS sprite active state no working?

Tags: css, css-sprites

can anyone help me find out what the problem is?  I'm trying to make the active state of the css sprite work.

At the moment, it is not doing anything

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="Contact"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li id="Manual"><a href="manual.html">Manual</a></li>
    <li id="FAQ"><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav {
    background:url("../img/nav_final.png") no-repeat;
    width: 372px;
    height: 47.5px;
    margin: 70px auto;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav li, #nav a {
    height: 47.5px;
    display: block;
}

#nav li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    text-indent: -9999em;
}

#Contact { width: 120px; }
#Manual { width: 140px; }
#FAQ { width: 112px; }

#Contact a:hover, #Contact a:active { background:url("../img/nav_final.png") 0px -47.5px no-repeat; }
#Manual a:hover,  #Manual a:active  { background:url("../img/nav_final.png") -118px -47.5px no-repeat; }
#FAQ a:hover,  #FAQ a:active  { background:url("../img/nav_final.png") -260px -47.5px no-repeat; }
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: open firebug and look at the 'ul id="nav"' and see if the background image is loading if not then troubleshoot the image path.

Comment: the path works as the hover state works.  Just not the current states

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The :active selector is when you have the mouse key pressed down. Not when you are at the actual link location.

Comment: Are there any ways to fix this?

Comment: You can make a class called: active. And then add that class to the link that is active in the html-file or with javascript or a server-side script.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the background-image on the links inside the nav. Also a `background-repeat: no-repeat` causes problems when using negative positioning.

[Here is a reduced test-case](http://dabblet.com/gist/2343300)